# Circuit corresponding to positively skewed bode plot

Tags: linear, bode-plot

I have the following bode plot for an unknown circuit

[image]

It seems like there's underdamping going on, but otherwise I'm not really sure what sort of circuit would produce a plot like this, other than that I'm sure that all the elements in it are linear.

Comment: Why do I see negative frequencies?

Comment: @VladimirCravero, corrected the graph

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fTU5a2.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

You know that the gain is dropping rapidly with decreasing frequency, so you can suppose that the circuit is capacitor coupled.  You have a resonance so you can suppose that there's another reactive element like an inductor.  You have damping, so you have some resistance, and you have 0db of gain at high frequencies, so the bottom divider element must go high impedance at high frequencies (i.e. it's inductive).

Something like a capacitor from the input to output with an inductor and resistor in series from the output to ground would give a response like this.

Comment: Does the ordering of the inductor and resistor matter with respect to ground and output?

Comment: They are series elements, so it doesn't matter.